# Access windows command line from chrome (or firefox) extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is it possible to write an extension that accesses the windows command line in an arbitrary fashion?  Alternatively is there some browser out there that provides this capability.

Why?  On our manufacturing floor we have a couple of applications that need to access hardware on the PC.  Currently we have to write, and deploy small apps to do this, but it would be great to deploy them from the browser.

Clearly under normal circumstances this is a security issue, but is it possible to add an extension that would allow this to be circumvented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Firefox you can certainly do this.

Firefox has [4 types of extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons): ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions), [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), [Bootstraped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), or [Overlay/XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions)).

WebExtensions can not currently do this, and may never be able to do so (they are like Google Chrome extensions). Mozilla is strongly moving towards having only WebExtensions and Add-on SDK extensions. Thus, this should be an Add-on SDK extension.

You will want to use the [system/child_process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process) API, which is an implementation of the [node.js child_process API](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). You can gain access to the API with a line like:

```
var childProcess = require("sdk/system/child_process");
```

You can then easily [create a new process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation) and communicate with it using [stdin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process#Writing_to_child_process%27_stdin), [stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout), and [stderr](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stderr).

You will have to do all communication between the child process in your main (background) script. All [communication with the webpage you are viewing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts) must be in a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts). You can choose to only load the content script when the URL matches certain pages, or domains using [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) (which will be one part of not having any arbitrary website being able to run commands). You will need to [pass messages back and forth through from your content script to your background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on).

So, basically, communication will look like:

Web page ⟷ content script ⟷ background script ⟷ child process

It would be relatively easy to implement a message passing scheme that allows the web page to run arbitrary commands, provide command line arguments, input data, and receive output data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend doing it using a browser.  Browsers and their security models evolve very quickly and you're likely to find yourself constantly fighting the changes.

Instead, if your computers are in a domain, use group policy to deploy your apps.  Here's a guide:  http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/the-guide-to-deploying-software-using-group-policy

If your factory computers are not in a domain or the group policy looks too complicated, then you could have an icon shortcut that runs a batch file that copies the apps down to the factory machine from a local source.  Or if you're trying to run the apps while unattended, you could have that batch file run as a scheduled task.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers, you could use Native Messaging to achieve that. [This link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/Native_Messaging) tells us there is a project to add this native messaging api to WebExtensions.

For chrome extensions, see [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) for more details.

Basically, you would need an extension and a native host, establishing communications between extensions and native host, extension is used to receiving commands from browser while native host is actually executing anything you want the command line to do.

Comment: if I understand, then I still have to implement a "native host" right?

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn, yes, extension has no access to those native apis.